# PHP - Files not moving to directory

Tags: php

I'm struggling to work a multiple image posting into a newly generated directory. Can someone help me? I've narrowed down the problem to the fact it doesn't move_uploaded_files...

code:

```
<?php
  //Basic types
    //Create Subdirectory
      //Set the subdirectory name
      $subdir = $_POST['folderName'];
      //set the directory path name
      $dir = ("./uploads/" . $subdir);
      //make the directory
      if(mkdir($dir, 0777)){
      }

  foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $f => $name) {
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $name);
    $extension = end($temp);
    //Set file type and size
    if ((($_FILES['file']['type'][$f] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES['file']['type'][$f] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES['file']['type'][$f] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES['file']['type'][$f] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES['file']['size'][$f] < 2000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
      if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$f] > 0){
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES['file']['error'][$f] . "<br>";
      } else {
        //if the file exists within the directory
        if (file_exists($dir . $name)){
          echo "<p>File Already Exists</p>";
        } else {
          $names = $_FILES['file']['name'][$f];

          //move the files you upload into the newly generated folder.
          if (move_uploaded_file($names, "$dir/$name")){
            echo "<p>Moved</p>";
          } else {
            echo "<p>not moved</p>";
          }
          //send the file path to the database.

          echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;url=test.php'>";
        }
      }
    } else {
      $error =  "Invalid file";
    }
  }
?>

<body> 
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <p>Enter the name of Folder:</p>
  <input type="text" name="folderName">

  <p>File:</p>
  <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple="multiple" >

  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<?php
  $path = "./uploads/";

  $dir = opendir($path) or die ("unable to open directory");

  while ($file = readdir($dir)){
    if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == ".DS_Store" || $file == "test.php" || $file == "testCreate.php" || $file == "testDeleteDir.php"){
      continue;
    }

    echo "<a href='$path$file'>$file</a><a href='testDeleteDir.php?dir=$file'> Delete</p><br />";
  }

  closedir($dir);
?>


</body>
```

Basically, my code generates a new subfolder within the folder /uploads. I'm trying to gain access to that folder and move my uploaded images there, but it's not doing the trick. Someone help me?

Thank you! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that folders created?

Comment: off topic, but two points 1) What happens if someone posts a folder name of "../" ? - you will want to clean your user input 2) perhaps consider using `$path = $_FILES['image']['name']; $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` to get the file extension.

Comment: @RajivRisi The folder is created in the desired location. the problem is linking to the folder to upload.

Comment: @CarCzar I'll figure that out later, but it doesn't matter too much. it's going to be part of a form, so the folder name with be equivalent to the title the user puts in. how would I use what you typed up there in my code? can you show me?

Comment: @HayoFriese Please read up on user input sanitization so that you understand the related security implications. http://www.dreamhost.com/dreamscape/2013/05/22/php-security-user-validation-and-sanitization-for-the-beginner/ as for point 2) instead of exploding the filename on the `.` character, and fussing with that mess, you would use the pathinfo function to find the dile extenstion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$names = $_FILES['file']['name'][$f];
```

Should be

```
$names = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$f];
```

Comment: Thanks! i had it like that last time, and it didn't work, now it did!!!! LIFE SAVER